# Ray wu DNA sequencing methodology understanding

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, history

I'm trying to understand the method which Ray Wu, developed to sequence the DNA 5' cohesive ends of a lamda phage. I'm reading these two papers written by him, but i stuck at the point where he uses the <sup>32</sup>P nucleotides.

[Structure and base sequence in the cohesive ends of bacteriophage lambda DNA](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283668800129)

[Nucleotide sequence analysis of DNA: II. Complete nucleotide sequence of the cohesive ends of bacteriophage λ DNA](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022283671901057)

It's not clear to me, by reading the papers, the step in which he runs the polymerization of the DNA. Did he use all the <sup>32</sup>P nucleotides at once or each one at a time. As i understood he made the DNA pol to use the tritiated nucleotides to fill in the gaps of the 5' cohesive ends and then he cleaves with a DNAase in many  oligonucleotides which later fractionize with electrophoresis. If he added all tritiated nucleotides at once how did he recognize which one is at a specific place ?

Can someone describe the process in more detail using step by step aproach?

Thank you,

Comment: Those two articles are located behind a paywall

Comment: Do you want me, to upload them somewhere else or is it illegal?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer (I'm a biochemist). Don't worry, I think I have a new account for access. So you're still seeking an explanation? How did you come across these classics?

Comment: I just wanted to see how people used to think back then with their only tool the analytical chemistry and some little knowledge of enzymes. 2 days i read it again and again and tried to put an order of the process/method he was used. His work is about 28 pages and he finally read about 20 nucleotides. Maxam's and Sanger's  papers are around 8 pages and they cloud sequence 100 - 1000 nucleotides at once. Times are changing and it seems fascinating to me knowing a little bit of history. If you want the papers, let me know.

Comment: That's very cool (IMHO). As my martial arts sensei used to say "You gots to know the basic fundamentals" (he was not a native english speaker). I think the second paper has the full story(?) because based on the abstract in the first paper he only found out which bases were present, not the order or sequence. Can you upload PDFs here to Stackexchange as attachments? I don't remember how that works.

Comment: What stage are you at in your education/training?

Comment: After reading your original post again, I am going to speculate that the combination of isotope labelling and DNAse digestion means he used a combination of something called nearest neighbour analysis, probably coupled with wandering spot thin layer chromatography (TLC)

Comment: Nope, according to this review article I was wrong "It was around this time that various researchers began to adapt their methods in order to sequence DNA, aided by the recent purification of bacteriophages with DNA genomes, providing an ideal source for testing new protocols. Making use of the observation that Enterobacteria phage λ possessed 5′ overhanging ‘cohesive' ends, Ray Wu and Dale Kaiser used DNA polymerase to fill the ends in with radioactive nucleotides, supplying each nucleotide one at a time and measuring incorporation to deduce sequence [17,18]"

Comment: Check out this site: http://www.whatisbiotechnology.org/exhibitions/sanger/dna

Comment: I couldn't create attachments in comments so here are the links for the files
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=73908298645007027481

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30732501249180823829

I just started my Msc. at protein biotechnology.
I've already read that page. All i wanted was to understand the chemical perspective they used.

Comment: Also,  by reading these papers, a new question came in the air posted here. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52809/doesnt-the-radioactive-labeled-molecules-of-dntps-or-dna-harm-themselves-or-the

If you have an idea for that too... let us know :-)

Comment: I am not going to post this as an answer, but I have skimmed the paper, and it is an absolute beast.  Some facts worth noting. They do not use electrophoresis, they use ionophoresis.  They also use a scintillation counter to calculate the number of molecules of radio labelled dNTP incorporated.  After ionophoresis they purify the radioactive peaks and analyse those by nuclease digestion, and nearest neighbour analysis.  Essentially they use the labels to purify the new oligos, and then fragment them to figure out the sequence of every dinucleotide. Then they build a map.